# why output statement not showing integer output

Tags: java, probability

Question:    For a single toss of 2 fair (evenly-weighted) dice, find the probability that the values rolled by each die will be different and their sum is 6.

what is wrong in my code
the last 3 print statements are not working

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter");

        int count=0;
        int deno=36;

        for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
            for(int j=1; i<7; j++){
            if((i+j)==6 && i!=j){
                count++;
                }
            }

        }

        for(int i = 2; i<=10; i++){
            if(count%i==0 && deno%i==0){
                count=count/i;
                deno=deno/i;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(count); 
        System.out.println("/"); 
        System.out.println(deno); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo leading to infinite loop - `for(int j=1; i<7; j++){` -> `for(int j=1; j<7; j++){`

Comment: ith last 3 printout statements not giving any noutput on console

Comment: kindly post the changed code

Comment: thank you buddy thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Often you could easily find these kind of mistakes by printing `i` and `j` in your loop and you'll see what's wrong.

```
for(int i=1; i<7; i++){
    for(int j=1; i<7; j++){  // <--- TYPO
        if((i+j)==6 && i!=j){
            System.out.println("i " + i);
            System.out.println("j " + j);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

You should change the second for loop to this:

```
 for(int j=1; j<7; j++){
```